# Реализовать функцию фильтра массива по указанному типу данных

Tags: javascript, массивы, функции, типы-данных, callback

Написать функцию `filterBy()`, которая будет принимать в себя 2 аргумента. Первый аргумент - массив, который будет содержать в себе любые данные, второй аргумент - тип данных.
Функция должна вернуть новый массив, который будет содержать в себе все данные, которые были переданы в аргумент, за исключением тех, тип которых был передан вторым аргументом. То есть, если передать массив `['hello', 'world', 23, '23', null]`, и вторым аргументом передать `string`, то функция вернет массив `[23, null]`.

Answer (score -1):

Думаю как-то так

```js
function filterBy(array, type) {
 return array.reduce((res, currentItem) => { if ( typeof currentItem != type) {  res.push(currentItem);} return res} , []); 
}

 console.log(filterBy(['hello', 'world', 23, '23', null], 'string'))
```

Answer (score -2):

Надо уточнить, что будет возвращаться без второго аргумента, отличного от стринг...
Вы уверенны, что массив именно такой - (смешанный и одномерный)?

Делаешь приблизительно так(вариант не оптимальный, без unset);

```
function filter_by ($arr, $what){
  $n_arr = array();
  if($what){
    if(is_array($arr) && count($arr)>0 ){
       foreach($n_arr as $el){
         if(gettype($el) != $what ){
            $n_arr[] = $el;
         }
       }

    }else{
       echo "Первый аргумент должен быть (НЕ ПУСТЫМ) массивом!</br>";
    }
  }else{
       echo "Первый аргумент должен быть не пустым и указывать на тип!</br>";
  }
  return $n_arr;
}
```

Comment: да массив смешанный и одномерный, а какой тип данных нужно убрать это нужно запращивать у пользователя, если он ничего не введёт или укажет не тип данных запросить ещё раз через цикл можна

Comment: Самое простое что пришло в голову. Добавил код в первый ответ.

Answer (score -2):

```js
let items = ['hello', 'world', 23, '23', null]

const filterBy = (arr, type) => arr.filter(item => typeof item !== type)

console.log(filterBy(items, "string"))
```